# Is it Possible to obtain User from Painless script when updating doc from Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Using Elastic Painless scripting, is it possible to get the user submitting a document update via the Kibana GUI?

Using ingest pipelines, I've tried to append the Security User to the context

```
{
    "set_security_user": {
      "field": "_security",
      "properties": [
        "roles",
        "username",
        "email",
        "full_name",
        "metadata",
        "api_key",
        "realm",
        "authentication_type"
      ]
    }
  }
```

However regardless of which user is submitting a change to the document (via the Kibana GUI) it always sets it to:

```
...
"roles": [
        "kibana_system",
        "cloud-internal-enterprise_search-server"
      ],
      "realm": {
        "name": "found",
        "type": "file"
      },
      "authentication_type": "REALM",
      "username": "cloud-internal-enterprise_search-server"
 ...
```

**Context:**
What I'm trying to achieve is an additional layer of restrictions when users are modifying the Enterprise Search indexes. I want Developer Roles to be able to see all the configuration items within App Search (Enterprise Search via Kibana), but to only be able to read and not write. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this using the standard Enterprise Search roles which give Admins, Owners and Devs full read/write permissions for the engine.

Comment: I have done some test, no issues on my side. which version are you running ? are you sure all user connect using different account ?

Comment: @Paulo - Using version 8.4.3 - In the ingest pipeline simulator it works fine, but the moment it's actually being executed, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Paulo I've added what I'm trying to achieve, which is essentially a "read only" developer account.